# Join by attribute when unique identifier has multiple rows using ArcMap 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins

I would like to join the attributes of one polygon layer to another polygon layer by their common ID. The problem is that in layer A, each ID has multiple rows, because each represent shapes from the layer B cut in multiple pieces (intersected with other information) and I need that information to be replicated each time within the boundaries of the layer B. Is there a way to join by attribute, so that the target layer B repeats rows of the adjoining Layer A, when the ID in Layer A occurs multiple times?

Comment: Have you done any research in the ArcGIS documentation on joins, relates, and relationship classes? http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/decidi-1810045288.htm What license level do you have available, Basic (previously known as ArcView), Standard (ArcEditor), or Advanced (ArcInfo)?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you start by reviewing the [help files on Joins](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/About_joining_and_relating_tables/005s0000002n000000/) so that you understand the relationship types (one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many) and their implications.

Yes, there are two ways to do what you want. However I do want to point out (if it's not already clear and desired) you're going to end up with *A* number of *B* polygons stacked on top of each other unless you're trying to *combine* those attributes, which would be aggregation. I'm not entirely clear on what result you're trying to achieve. It doesn't make a lot of sense to apply a single attribute value from a piece to a whole.

A regular join does not support one-to-many relationships. It will only return the first found record. However a [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) does have an option to support one-to-many and should work in this case since your A's are derived from your B's.  The other option is the [Make Query Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006r000000) tool, the results of which have to be saved to be made permanent.